# Pagination with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am doing a web scraping project for this site.
https://yellowpages.com.eg/en/search/fast-food
I managed to scrape the data but I am struggling with the pagination
As I want to make a loop that scrapes the next page button and then uses the scraped URL from the next button to do the same process.

```py
url = 'https://yellowpages.com.eg/en/search/fast-food'
while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    pages = soup.find_all('ul', class_='pagination center-pagination')
    for page in pages:
        nextpage = page.find('li', class_='waves-effect').find('a', {'aria-label': 'Next'})
        if nextpage:
            uu = nextpage.get('href')
            url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com.eg' + str(uu)
            print(url)
        else:
            break
```

This code returns the next URL in the pagination order and then breaks out of loop.

Comment: It's not the next page URL is scrapable on the second page all I want is a way to make my loop works with the resulting URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
nextpage =page.find('li', class_='waves-effect').find('a', {'aria-label' : 'Next'})
```

does return the Next button, but only as long as the Previous button is not there, meaning that it breaks as soon as you leave the first page (it returns None).

Instead, `page.find_all('li', class_='waves-effect')` returns the Next and the Previous button.

To (maybe) robustly get the Next button, change your line to

```
nextpage =page.find_all('li', class_='waves-effect')[-1].find('a', {'aria-label' : 'Next'})
```